# How to find heap memory of my iOS app using malloc_zone_statistics in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

Using malloc_zone_statistics , heap memory of iOS app in obj-c can be found as shown below.

```
#import <malloc/malloc.h>
malloc_statistics_t stats;
malloc_zone_statistics(NULL, &stats);
printf("%zu",stats.size_allocated);
```

How to use the same in swift? when I do the same in swift as : 
var stat:malloc_statistics_t; 
malloc_zone_statistics(nil, stat);
print(stat.size_allocated);

I get the error as - Cannot convert value of type 'malloc_statistics_t' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?'.

Comment: Have you tried https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119906?

Comment: Yes, but when I do the same in swift  as :  var stat:malloc_statistics_t malloc_zone_statistics(nil, stat) ;   print(stat.size_allocated) ;   I get below errors as - Cannot convert value of type 'malloc_statistics_t' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<malloc_statistics_t>?'

Comment: Please add this info to the question. It's an important bit of research.